# Adapting mouse based game to touch controls

Tags: camera, touch, unity-game-engine, sliding

I developed a basic game in which the camera can be moved across the map using the WASD keys and I wanted to adapt the basic button actions to work on a touch screen , but I am unsure how to start.

Here's the c# code I currently have for moving the camera

```
if (Input.anyKey && allowInput)
    {
        moved = false;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) { moved = true; Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed); }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) { moved = true; Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * speed);}
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) { moved = true; Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * speed);}
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) { moved = true; Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed); }

if (OnCamManuallyMoved != null && moved)
        {
            Vector3 pos = tr.position;
            if (pos.x < min_xz.x) pos.x = min_xz.x;
            if (pos.x > max_xz.x) pos.x = max_xz.x;
            if (pos.z < min_xz.y) pos.z = min_xz.y;
            if (pos.z > max_xz.y) pos.z = max_xz.y;
            tr.position = pos;

            OnCamManuallyMoved(); // call callback
        }
    }
```

Comment: Three options come to mind: buttons on the screen, "hotspots" around the edges of the screen, or interpreting any longtouch-drag as a desire to move the camera. If you're not worried about multi-touch, `Input.mousePosition` works as an alias for the player's finger position (or zero when they're not touching the screen).

Comment: I am attempting to get the game camera to drag by using long touch drags because i plan on adding multitouch to accommodate for the extra buttons/commands the game requires .